# Save excel as pdf changing its orientation to horizontal

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, orientation

I have an excel sheet with too many columns, so when I save it as a PDF the file its in too many pages and its not easy to read . I need to save the sheet as pdf but before I want to change its orientation to horizontal so I can read the pdf with no problem. Is the same you can do when you print but I want it when I save an excel file as pdf.
Is there any option I can choose?

```
 I dont mind if someone gives me a code for a macro using my selection as an object.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Under the "Page Layout" tab, click the "Orientation" option and then select "Landscape."

Then create your PDF as usual.

Comment: This answer doesn't work with Office Excel 2021. Maybe this used to work on older versions of Excel.

Answer (score -4):

You can save Excel files in PDF, even without using Excel. I use a program Universal Document Converter ([http://www.print-driver.com/how-to/save-excel-as-pdf](http:///http://www.print-driver.com/how-to/save-excel-as-pdf)). This program allows you to quickly and easily create print-ready PDF-files on the basis of the original spreadsheets Excel.

Comment: please describe how the user can get the desired orientation